# dynamodb in the browser getting started

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am little confused about retrieving data from dynamodb ... connecting is not an issue cause I am getting `The provided key element does not match the schema`

:[the example provided from AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-examples.html#Amazon_DynamoDB)

```
var table = new AWS.DynamoDB({params: {TableName: 'MY_TABLE'}});
var key = 'UNIQUE_KEY_ID';
var itemParams = {Item: {id: {S: key}, data: {S: 'data'}}};

  table.getItem({Key: {id: {S: key}}}, function(err, data) {
    console.log(data.Item); // print the item data
  });
```

[image]

in my case the unique key is "time" and what I want to do is retrieve by key (not unique)

Answer (score 0):

getItem only works on the primary key. From the docs: *The GetItem operation returns a set of attributes for the item with the given **primary** key.* See [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#getItem-property).

To solve this, create a Global Secondary Index that has "key" as HASH and "time" as RANGE. Then do a query operation using that index as `IndexName`:

```
var params = {
  IndexName: 'your-new-GSI-index',
  KeyConditionExpression: '#key = :key',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#key': 'key },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':key': { S: yourKeyVar } }
}
table.query(params, callback);
```

(did not test this code, but should work)

Comment: I dont think second index is the solution, My logic says that if it;s possible to retrieve the document via aws exlplorer , it should be with aws sdk

Comment: Well by default the explorer just does a scan and you can filter on non-index keys later. Possible, but that's super inefficient and expensive as you consume a read capacity for every row in your table (not just the ones you want to retrieve, you need `query` for that).